# 9 digit floating point number conversion

Tags: binary, ieee

1. Format A
   There is 1 sign bit.
   There are k = 5 exponent bits. The exponent bias is 15.
   There are n = 3 fraction bits.

Those are the special ieee parameters

Binary number 
 1 00111 010

After all the math I get -5/1024

However, my buddy got -704

Who is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the calculation below shows, it appears that *you* are correct, and the correct answer is `-5/1024`:

```
Input: 1 00111 010
Mantissa: 1.010 base 2
Exponent: 111 base 2 = 7 base 10; 7 − 15 = -8
De-normalize: 1.010 base 2 × 2^-8 = .00000001010
```

The following table shows how you can convert the denormalized number into a base 10 decimal:

```
Exponent |    2^-8    |    2^-9     |    2^-10     |     2^-11     |
Decimal  | 0.00390625 | 0.001953125 | 0.0009765625 | 0.00048828125 |
Bit      |     1      |     0       |      1       |      0        |
Value    | 0.00390625 |     0       | 0.0009765625 |      0        |

Total = 0.00390625 + 0.0009765625 = 0.0048828125
```

This value must then be negated because the sign bit is set.  So the final result is `-0.0048828125`.   This equals `-5/1024` which you originally got.

Here is a [link to a great site](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/ftod.html) which shows how to do the conversion step by step.